# Media query is not responsive

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am working on my first ever media query for a class and to me my code looks like the example we were given, but when I test it on Chrome using the developer tools, it is not responsive. I am just trying to make it so that the list will be vertical (block) when viewed on a phone and horizontal (inline block) when viewed on a bigger screen. Can anyone help me see what I did wrong?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Ruslan Display';
}

ul {
  background: #3399ff;
  padding: 20px;
}

#favorites li {
  background: #cce5ff;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

@media(min-width:375px;
) {
  #favorites li {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanalei+Fill|Ruslan+Display" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="My First Site for Web Fundamentals">
  <title>My First Webpage</title>
</head>


<body>
  <p>This is my very first attempt at putting info up on a Webpage using a a media query for responsive design. <br></p>
  <p>Below is a list of my favorite people. It should change format based on whether or not you view it on an iPhone or a desktop.</p>
    <ul id="favorites">
      <li>My husband, Brian</li>
      <li>My kids, Louis and Brady</li>
      <li>My parents, Terry and Steve</li>
      <li>My brother, Steven</li>
      <li>My best friend, Missy</li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon from your media query param; this is invalidating your query.

`@media(min-width:375px;)`
should be
`@media(min-width:375px)`

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to put your html into the snippet, there were html errors highlighted in red. You had break tags (`<br>`with forward slashes (`</br>`) that were being picked up as incorrect (the forward slashes are unnecessary). Also, the closing paragraph tag wasn't being recognised as being matched (that may be a shortcoming of stacksnippets, but still, it's good to close a paragraph after a block of text instead of using multiple `br` tags). The HTML errors probably contributed more to your issue than your css. The online [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/) is a very useful tool for checking for html errors.. just a tip! .

Hope this helps